# Permisison issues with Qt app on MAC OS Sierra

Tags: macos, qt, sign

I’m developing a cross platform application with Qt 5.6. When the application starts, it creates a single file on the app directory:

```
QFile file;

// /MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS
file.setFileName(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + QString("/file.csv"); 
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate);

...

file.close();
```

This works perfectly fine with old OS X versions, but since Sierra, this file is not regenerated (only if the app is downloaded from internet). Note that I do not publish my app on the MAC store, I simply use a .dmg file.

Here are few tests that I’ve done:

- Compiling the app and launching on Sierra => **OK**
- Compiling the app, create a .dmg and launching on Sierra => **OK**
- Compiling the app, create a .dmg (that I uploaded), downloading and launching the app on Sierra => **FAIL**

I think the problem is linked to permissions access. This single command line solve my problem, but of course I can’t give that solution for my users:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

This is how I sign my application:

```
# Signing application
codesign --force --deep --sign "Developer ID Application: *** ***" /MyPath/MyApp.app 

# Validating signature
spctl --assess --verbose /MyPath/MyApp.app
```

And here is my info.plist file, generated by Qt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>mac_app_icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Created by Qt/QMake</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.myapp</string>
    <key>NOTE</key>
    <string>This file was generated by Qt/QMake.</string>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I’m not very familiar with MAC signing tool, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, however it has been best practice to store data away from executables for some time. Writing at the location of `QApplication::applicationDirPath()` is not advisable.

Ideally you should be storing runtime information in standard locations:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum

```
QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation).first();
```

Comment: You're totaly right. Unfortunatly, I don't have choice for this specific file.

Comment: @Sierra I don't know from personal experience, however I would probably try a GUI sudo to run the command you need, the user would then be prompted for the password and carry on as normal: http://www.performantdesign.com/2009/10/26/cocoasudo-a-graphical-cocoa-based-alternative-to-sudo/

Comment: Yes, it would be perfect but `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` seems to be deprecated since OS_X 10.7